# I've changed auto generated namespaces in Visual Studio C# recently, and now I've an error on line 0 and column 0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've changed namespaces in both files (`GuiMenu.cs` and `GuiMenu.Designer.cs`) recently (from `MyProject.GuiMenu` to `GUI`), but only now I've got such warning:

```
Warning 1   The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the following classes in the file: 

PropetiesWindow --- The base class 'MyProject.GuiMenu' could not be loaded.  
Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects have been built.
Line 0 Column 0
```

It looks like visual studio doesn't like this namespace, and trying to use old one. What is wrong ? By the way, recently I had warning like this : Can't find class `MyProject.GuiMenu.MyClass`. But this class exists in `GUI.MyClass`, fortunately this warning has disappeared. PS: I tried to remove bin and obj folders from object, doesn't help.

Comment: Your going to need to post code

Comment: Do a search and replace for MyProject.GuiMenu. If you don't use the refactoring tools and do this in right order on code that compiles, VS quite often makes a mess of it. Do it across the solution as well.